# Adding JS to page if IE in Razor C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I have some Jauery function that goes like this

```
// Check if the userAgent contains "msie"
$(function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
       alert('IE');
    }
    else {
       alert('Not IE');
    }
});
```

What i need now is to add different js files to page when diferrent browser, combine Razor C# template engine something like this

```
// Check if the userAgent contains "msie"
$(function(){
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) { 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/timeline.js")"></script> 
   }
   else {
        @using (Script.Foot())
        { 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/jquery.isotope.min.js")"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/jquery.dpSocialTimeline.min.js")"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/jquery.dpSocialTimeline.values.js")"></script> 
        }
   }    
});
```

Is it possible to combine razor C# and javascript, like this example i have show?

**UPDATE
Tried something like this, does not work :(**

```
@using (Script.Foot())
{ 
<script>
// Check if the userAgent contains "msie"
$(function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) { 
        alert('This is IE');
        }
    else {   
        document.write('<script src="@Url.Content("~/jquery.isotope.min.js")"><\/script>');
        document.write('<script src="@Url.Content("~/jquery.dpSocialTimeline.min.js")"><\/script>');
        document.write('<script src="@Url.Content("~/Tjquery.dpSocialTimeline.values.js")"><\/script>');
}
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? (What makes you think it won't work?)

Comment: Please include details of how you know it is not valid. Eg. if you are getting an error message then include in the Q as reported to you (don't re-phrase it).

Comment: do you include jquery library before your scripts ? @Gorostas